# django messages get displayed only on the next request

Tags: django, message

I have a django app and I use messages in order to show some limits that user passes.

My problem is that all my messages are shown after the second request.

I mean, after adding a message and going to a page where the the message should be shown, I don't see it, but I start seeing it after a refresh.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably how those messages are intended to work: You "trigger" them e.g. to show success/failure and then redirect to another page where it's displayed. Remember: In case an action succeeded you should never stay on the page requested via POST but redirect so reloading won't re-POST whatever was sent.

Comment: OK. But is there a way to add a message in a view and see it in html that get rendered in this view?

Comment: @alexarsh You would just add the messages to the template context yourself

Comment: Yes, but I want to see it in all the following requests too.

Comment: then do both, simultaneously, while giving people high 5's.